# How do I change svg color while hovering its parent div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have one use-case where the HTML is nested as this :

```
<button className="btn">
  <span>
    <img className="logo" src={require("./like.svg").default} />
  </span>
Like
</button>
```

The button is a simple button with an icon at the beginning.

The `svg` is a like/love icon with a white background color. The hovering on an `svg` works as this :

```
// filter property is responsible for colors on svg element.
.logo {
  filter: invert(43%) sepia(0%) saturate(1%) hue-rotate(198deg)
    brightness(94%) contrast(94%);
}
```

Similarly, if I want to change color of an SVG icon while hovering , I can do it like this:

```
.logo:hover {
  filter: /<a different color>/
}
```

Now, What I want is to trigger .logo:hover when I'm hovering on the btn itself.

Meaning, while hovering the button, the SVG icon should also behave the similar hover color.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: You can apply any CSS you want if you load the external SVG with [the ``<load-file src="...">`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS selector that targets a `.logo` child of a hovered `.btn`:

```css
.btn:hover .logo {
  filter: /<a different color>/
}
```